# Preventing Underflow and Overflow

Tags: verilog

```
  module threshold(input[7:0] oLCD_R1,
                  input[7:0] oLCD_G1,
                  input[7:0] oLCD_B1,
                  input[7:0] Rcapture1,
                  input[7:0] Gcapture1,
                  input[7:0] Bcapture1,
                  input oDEN1,
                  output reg[7:0] oLCD_R2,
                  output reg[7:0] oLCD_G2,
                  output reg[7:0] oLCD_B2,
                  output oDEN2,
                  output  [7:0] Rlower,
                  output  [7:0] Rupper,
                  output  [7:0] Glower,
                  output  [7:0] Gupper,
                  output  [7:0] Blower,
                  output  [7:0] Bupper
                );
assign Rlower = Rcapture1;
assign Rupper = Rcapture;
assign oDEN2 = oDEN1;

always @(*)
begin
     if (Rcaputre1 < 30)
     begin
     Rlower = 30;
     end
     if (Rcaputre1 > 225)
       begin
       Rupper = 225;
      end
end 
  begin
  if (
      ( ( Rcapture1 - 30  < oLCD_R1)  &&  (oLCD_R1 < Rcapture1 + 30 ) ) && 
      ( ( Gcapture1 - 30  < oLCD_G1)  &&  (oLCD_G1 < Gcapture1 + 30 ) ) &&
      ( ( Bcapture1 - 30  < oLCD_B1)  &&  (oLCD_B1 < Bcapture1 + 30 ) )
    )   

  begin
 oLCD_R2 = 255;
 oLCD_G2 = 192;
 oLCD_B2 = 0;
 end 
    else 
    begin   
     oLCD_R2 = oLCD_R1;
     oLCD_G2 = oLCD_G1;
     oLCD_B2 = oLCD_B1;
     end 
  end
 endmodule
```

i am trying to prevent underflow and overflow during subtraction and addition for my Rcapture but it appears that it cant work due to errors  of object 'Rlower' on left hand side of assignment must have a net type? i declare it as a `output reg` why do i still get this error for both `Rlower` and `Rupper`

so by changing the statement

```
assign Rlower = Rcapture1 ? Rcapture1 < 30  : Rlower == 30;
assign Rupper = Rcapture1 ? Rcapture1 < 225 : Rupper == 225;

assign Glower = Gcapture1 ? Gcapture1 < 30  : Glower == 30;
assign Gupper = Gcapture1 ? Gcapture1 < 225 : Gupper == 225;

assign Blower = Bcapture1 ? Bcapture1 < 30  : Blower == 30;
assign Bupper = Bcapture1 ? Bcapture1 < 225 : Bupper == 225;
```

will this stop the underflow and overflow problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regs` (and `output regs`) are assigned values in always blocks. Signals declared as a `wire` or `output` are considered to be "net-type", and they are assigned a value using an `assign` statement.

Either move `Rlower` into an `always` block, or remove the `reg` from the declaration. Same applies to `Rupper`.

Comment: Tried the method u suggested but it still not working the same error appear at statement `Rlower = 30` and `Rupper = 225` could it be due to not assigning them in an `always` block?

Comment: see: http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_veri_illegal_continuous_assignment.htm

Comment: You also have an error on the line `Rcapture1 = 30;` near the beginning of the `always` block - `Rcapture` is an input, and cannot be assigned a value.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding i forget to change the code here

Comment: i solved this by doing a assign `object` ? `object` : `object'` statement

Comment: yes - you can't give a value to a signal in both an `assign` statement and an `always` block.